# Summer '20 feature "Run Flow in System mode" & unlocked packages

Tags: salesforcedx, visual-workflow

Crossposting this from the SFDC dev forums:

I'm using the new Summer '20 feature Run Flows in System Mode (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_system_mode.htm).  It works fine in my scratch org - as in after saving the flow it shows 'Running in system mode' at the top(we are using unlocked packages and scratch orgs to develop and deploy changes between scratch orgs using bitbucket pipelines) but when pulling the changes from my scratch org shows no changes at all to the flow XML.  Is this new feature packageable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are using the same setup (with GitHub Actions). I just updated a flow to run in system mode last week, and that triggered a change on pull. It added the following line to the flows xml:

```
<runInMode>SystemModeWithoutSharing</runInMode>
```

When I install the updated package, the flow is updated to run in system mode, including showing "Runs as System" in top left corner in Flow Builder.